# when or why do i use Property.forName()?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

What is  the difference between :

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)  
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
.list();
```

and

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)  
.add( Property.forName("name").like("F%") )  
.list();
```

Or for that matter, difference between :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList() 
    .add(Property.forName("id").as("id")) 
    .add(Property.forName("name").as("name"))
```

and

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
    .add(Projections.property("Name"), "Name"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Property.forName("propName")` always returns you the matching `Property` instance.

Having said this, means there is no difference between the first two code snippets posted in your question. You should use `Property.forName("propName")` when you need to use that property multiple times in **Criteria** or **Query**. It is equivalent to using direct no. (`e.g. 11`) or using variable assigned to the no. (`e.g. int x = 11`) and use the variable everytime you need to use the no.

For more details, see [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing).

Now if I talk about the 2nd question (3rd & 4th code snippets), working of both is the same. The only difference is in the API being used.

In 3rd code snippet, you're getting the instance of `Property`, calling its `as()` method which is used to generate alias for that particular property and returns an instance of `SimpleProjection (subclass of Projection)`.

While in 4th code snippet, you're getting instance of `PropertyProjection (subclass of Projection)` by doing `Projections.property("Name")`.

So in both cases you're getting instance of `Projection`, which you're adding to `ProjectionsList`. Now ProjectionList is having 2 overloaded methods called `add()`. In 3rd code snippet you're calling `add()` that takes only instance of `Projection` as argument. In 4th code snippet you're calling another version of `add()`, that takes instance of `Projection` as first argument & `alias for the property of Projection` as the 2nd argument. So ultimately working of both is the same.

Comment: So, in the 3rd snippet, when I call the method `add(Projection)`, I'm giving the alias information too. And in the 4th snippet, im giving the alias information by calling the method `add(Projection,alias)`. Is that right?

Comment: Alias information is passed in both the cases. The API used is different. You can give alias to property by 2 ways: 1. using `Property.as("aliasName")` 2. using `ProjectionList.add(projection, aliasName)`.